# R and K, charcount (1.5.2) not giving correct result

Tags: c

Im going through the C Programming Language Book, R and K I think its referred to as.

I'm in Ubuntu doing all of this, and even copying and pasting the example directly from the file won't work.

This is what the book has

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 /* count characters in input; 1st version */
main()    {
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

And it is MEANT to read in a line of input, and tell you how many characters it has.

What happens, though, is after I hit enter, I just have a new line to input on.

In another question, I saw ctrl + d would create an EOF, so I tried that, but that gives me the wrong number (qwerty gets 7, for example).

What am I doing wrong/ is there a feature of Ubuntu that changes this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems ok, what exaclty happens when you hit ctrl+d?

Comment: it prints a number, 1 more than the expected one. I think its counting the newline character as a character.

Comment: The fact is that a newline __is__ character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it wrong, the program is **not meant** *to read in a line of input, and tell you how many characters it has.* It is intended to count the number of characters in *the whole* input so newline characters are counted to.

It will only stop when it sees a EOF character coming in the input.

Comment: Okay, but in the previous one, which puts out what you put in, why does it count newline as an EOF character?
'       c = getchar();
        while (c != EOF) {
            putchar(c);
            c = getchar(); 
'

Comment: The code worked well for me. If you don't want a new line try to write something and hit `Ctrl+d` twice. It will print number of chars on the same line. Can you try it?

Comment: In the previous one `putchar getchar etc` it didn't count newline as an EOF.  You could keep typing after pressing enter.  What happens is that output characters are buffered up until `getchar` outputs a newline character.